# Prove $(x-1)(y-1)>(e-1)^2$ where $x^y=y^x$, $y>x>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

> Let $x,y$ be different positive real numbers satisfying $x^y=y^x$.
> Prove $(x-1)(y-1)>(e-1)^2$.

We may suppose $a=\frac{y}{x}>1$. Then we obtain $x=a^{\frac{1}{a-1}},y=a^{\frac{a}{a-1}}.$ But how to go on?

Comment: The title does not quite match the inequality in the text.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe $x\ne y.$

Comment: I think he meant the $(y-1)^2$ term

Comment: That seems to be a very sharp estimate, look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2814345/42969.

Comment: The following is also true: $$(x-1)(y-1) > \left(\mathrm{e} - 1 + \frac{5}{8}\left(\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}} - \frac{\ln x}{x}\right)\right)^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

**If** you know that
$$x^y=y^x \implies x=-\frac{y}{\log (y)}W\left(-\frac{\log (y)}{y}\right)$$ where $W(t)$ is Lambert function, then
$$(x-1)(y-1)=(1-y)\Bigg[1+ \frac{y}{\log (y)}W\left(-\frac{\log (y)}{y}\right)\Bigg]=f(y)$$

$f'(y)$ cancels at $y=e$ and, at this point, $x=e$. The second derivative $$f''(e)=\frac{2 (2 e-5)}{3 e}\sim 0.107069~~ >~~ 0$$ confirms that this point is a minimum and $f(e)=(e-1)^2$.

**Edit**

As @Martin R commented, I did not prove that this is the global minimum.

In fact, this can be done using the fact that $\forall t \geq e$
$$W(t) \geq\log (t)-\log (\log (t))+\frac 12\frac{\log (\log (t))}{ \log (t)}=f(t)$$
$$W(t) \leq \log (t)-\log (\log (t))+\frac e{e-1}\frac{\log (\log (t))}{ \log (t)}=g(t)$$ or even better tha approximation of $W(t)$ I gave [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3992026/solving-nonlinear-equation-with-logarithmic-terms/3992496#3992496).

Comment: So $f(y)$ has a local minimum at $y=e$. Why is that the global minimum?

Comment: @MartinR. I agree : I did not prove that this is the global minimum. I shall try using bounds.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici How do you apply these bounds for $W(t)$ for $t\ge \mathrm{e}$? You need to deal with $W\left(-\frac{\log (y)}{y}\right)$ while $-\frac{\log (y)}{y} \in (-\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}}, 0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing your idea, let $a = 1+ \dfrac 1t, t > 0.$ Then, you can write your inequality as $xy-x-y > e^2-2e$, which is in terms of the variable $t:$

$$f(t) = t\ln\left(1+\frac 1t\right) + \ln\left(\left(1+\frac 1t\right)^{t+1}-2-\frac 1t\right) > 1+\ln(e-2).$$

[Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20xln%281%2B1%2Fx%29%20%2B%20ln%28%281%2B1%2Fx%29%5E%281%2Bx%29-2-1%2Fx%29%20%2C0%3Cx%3C10) says that this is indeed a decreasing function in $t$, so the infimum will be:
$$\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} f(t) = 1+ \ln(e-2).$$

Then, the only thing to show now is the fact that $f(t)$ is decreasing, but I suspect this will take an ugly computation.

EDIT: Actually, the derivative did not turn out to be too bad:

\begin{align}f'(t) &= \\
&\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{t^2} + \left(1+\dfrac 1t\right)^{t+1}{\left(2\ln\left(1+\frac 1t\right)-\dfrac 1t-\dfrac{1}{t+1}\right)} + \left(2+\dfrac{1}{t}\right)
\left(\dfrac{1}{1+t} - \ln\left(1+\dfrac{1}{t}\right)\right)}{\left(1+\dfrac 1t\right)^{t+1} - \dfrac 1t-2} &
\\<0\end{align}

Finally, the above is equivalent to:

$$\left(1+\dfrac 1t\right)^{t+1} > \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{t^2} + \left(2+\dfrac 1t\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{1+t} - \ln\left(1+\dfrac{1}{t}\right)\right)}{\dfrac{1}{t}+\dfrac{1}{1+t} - 2\ln\left(1+\dfrac{1}{t}\right)},$$

which I think should be doable by brute-force expanding with a Taylor's series etc.

Comment: I think we need much work to prove the last one. (+1)

Comment: @RiverLi yeah I tried a bit more then kind of gave up because it was getting nastier.

Answer (score 1):

(A comment rather than an answer
but much easier to enter)

This is an improvement
of my answer
[Proving or disproving: $a^b<b^a$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3988992/proving-or-disproving-abba/3989388#3989388)
where I showed that
if $x^{1/x} = y^{1/y}$
and
$1 < x < y$
then
$y > e^2/x$.

This is an improvement since
$(e-1)^2/(x-1)+1- e^2/x
=(e - x)^2/((x - 1) x)
\gt 0$.

Comment: Using something similar to dezdichado's transformation your inequality has a shorter proof: $x=(1+s)^{1/s}, y=(1+s)^{1+1/s}, g(s) = \ln (xy) = (1+2/s) \ln (1+s)$, [then](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+%281%2B2%2Fs%29*ln%281%2Bs%29) $$g'(s) = \frac{2}{s^2} \left( \frac{s(s+2)}{2(s+1)} - \ln (1+s) \right)$$ [next](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+s%28s%2B2%29%2F%282*%28s%2B1%29%29-ln%281%2Bs%29) $$h(s)=g'(s)\cdot \frac{s^2}{2} \implies h'(s) = \frac{s^2}{2(1+s)^2}>0$$

Comment: The last line is wrong! It should be \begin{align*}
&& y-\left[\frac{(e-1)^2}{x-1}+1\right]>\frac{e^2}{x}-\left[\frac{(e-1)^2}{x-1}+1\right]=\frac{(x-e)^2}{x(1-x)}<0,
\end{align*} which is useless.

Comment: @mengdie1982 Marty was saying your result is stronger than his. So yours can be used to prove his, but not the other way. It was "a comment rather than an answer".

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch of a proof:**

*Fact 1*: Let $f(u) = \frac{\ln u}{u}$. Then, $f(u)$ is strictly increasing on $(0, \mathrm{e})$,
and strictly decreasing on $(\mathrm{e}, \infty)$.

WLOG, assume $y < x$. From $x^y = y^x$, we have $\frac{\ln x}{x} = \frac{\ln y}{y}$.
By Fact 1, it is easy to prove that $1 < y < \mathrm{e} < x$.

We need to prove that $y > 1 + \frac{(\mathrm{e} - 1)^2}{x-1} \triangleq y_0$. Clearly, $y_0\in (1, \mathrm{e})$.
By Fact 1, it suffices to prove that $f(y) > f(y_0)$
or $\frac{\ln x}{x} > f(y_0)$. It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{\ln x}{x} > \frac{\ln\left( 1 + \frac{(\mathrm{e} - 1)^2}{x-1}\right)}{1 + \frac{(\mathrm{e} - 1)^2}{x-1}}, \ \forall x > \mathrm{e}.$$
It is true. But my proof is not nice. (Hint: Use Fact 2, then use derivative.)

*Fact 2*: $\frac{\ln v}{v} \ge \frac{(2\mathrm{e} + 10)v - 16\mathrm{e} + 4\mathrm{e}^2}
{(3\mathrm{e} - 3)v^2 + (16\mathrm{e} - 4\mathrm{e}^2)v - 19\mathrm{e}^2 + 7\mathrm{e}^3}$ for all $v \ge \mathrm{e}$.
(Hint: Take derivative.)

**Remark 1**: I propose the following problem:

Let $0 < y < x$ such that $\frac{\ln x}{x} = \frac{\ln y}{y} = a$ ($a>0$). Prove that
$$(x-1)(y-1) > \left(\mathrm{e} - 1 + \frac{5}{8}\left(\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}} - a\right)\right)^2.$$

By the way, there are many similar problems in MSE or AoPS. These problems has the following description:
Let $f(z)$ be a unimodal function. Let $f(x) = f(y) = a$. Then $g(x, y) \ge h(a)$.

See my closed post:
[Inequalities involving roots of some functions (e.g., $\frac{\ln x}{x}$, $x\ln x$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3757996/inequalities-involving-roots-of-some-functions-e-g-frac-ln-xx-x-ln-x)
For example,
[Estimate the bound of the sum of the roots of $1/x+\ln x=a$ where $a>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725944/estimate-the-bound-of-the-sum-of-the-roots-of-1-x-ln-x-a-where-a1),
[let $f(x) = (x-1)\ln x$, and given $0 < a < b$. If $f(a) = f(b)$, prove that $\frac{1}{\ln a}+\frac{1}{\ln b} < \frac{1}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2792428/let-fx-x-1-ln-x-and-given-0-a-b-if-fa-fb-prove-that-f)

Comment: this whole class of similar problems are very interesting. It seems to me that if someone develops a method of finding an asymptotic expansion of $x = x(y)$, the larger root, in terms of the smaller $y$, then it should be widely applicable to all the related questions.

Comment: @dezdichado I am interested in more elementary approaches. For example, some solutions use the Lambert W function, but sometimes it is not necessary. If $x, y$ can be separated (e.g., $y > 1 + \frac{(\mathrm{e}-1)^2}{x-1}$), then we may use the approach in this answer.  The difficult case is that $x, y$ can not be separated without using special functions.